# Help with Validation Rule on Contact

Tags: validation-rule

I want to Create a validation rule on contact object so that if the user profile = Services User, the Contact Name field is not editable.

Solution :

```
AND(ISCHANGED(FirstName),
    ISCHANGED(LastName),
    $Profile.Name <>'Services User')
```

Here my validation rule is not performing as expected.

Anyone can help with above requirement

Comment: Why not just use field level security?

Comment: This should be *two* validation rules so that the user can identify which field caused the error. Combining rules rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would echo @AdrianLarson in that field level security is probably the better approach for this. You would change the FLS for the 'Services User' so that they may only read the FirstName and LastName fields on Contact.

In your validation rule you are checking that BOTH FirstName and LastName changed when I think you really want OR for if either of them changed. You're also checking for a Profile name that is NOT EQUAL to 'Services User' but in your ask you say that you want this rule to be enforced for those Profiles only. Validation rules take effect when the expression in them evaluates to TRUE.

This should cover what you are looking for:

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(FirstName), 
        ISCHANGED(LastName)
    ),
    $Profile.Name = 'Services User'
)
```